# Redux Thunk getState() is returning all states

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Just discovered that I can use the getState() to pass state values to action creators. However I am noticing that getState() is returning all the combined states rather than the one specified in the argument. What am I doing wrong, as I don't suppose this is the correct behavior?

Reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { reducer as reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import authReducer from "./authReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  form: reduxForm
});
```

Action creator snippet:

```
export const handleProviderToken = token => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  let testState = getState("auth");
  console.log(testState); 
  const res = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/testEndpoint`);
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};
```

The **console.log(testState)** is showing me the entire state tree object (auth and form, rather than just auth).

Comment: How would redux even know which part of the state you're interested in? The only thing linking your action creator to a specific reducer is some dispatch call in the action, which fires an action for which a case in a reducer exists somewhere. It would have to introspect a lot of code to "guess" this information. Even that isn't enough, it would also have to examine how your reducers are combined. Hence it is agnostic to that.

Comment: I thought that the way Redux knows about which state is by passing the state as an argument to getState().. but now I understand how it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting redux-thunk documentation

> The inner function receives the store methods dispatch and getState as
>   parameters.

and quoting from redux's documentation

> getState()  Returns the current state tree of your application. It is
>   equal to the last value returned by the store's reducer.

So the getState you pass thanks to redux-thunk, is actually redux's getState() function itself and thus it is the default behavior.

To get a specific value from your state tree, you can either use one of the following

```
const { auth } = getState() 
// OR
const testState = getState()
const auth = testState.auth
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the correct behavior. [From docs](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#getstate()):

> Returns the current state tree of your application. It is equal to the
>   last value returned by the store's reducer.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct behavior. You will need to pick the reducer key from the complete state.

```
export const handleProviderToken = token => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  let testState = getState();
  let authReducer = testState.auth; 
  const res = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/testEndpoint`);
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What works in similar case for me is

```
const lastFetchedPage =getState().images.lastFetchedPage;
```

I do not know how it goes with guidelines, however.